# Getting my php file to work with my html file

Tags: php, html

So I want my contact form to work on my site so I wrote some php to make it work. Here is the code: (form_process.php)

```
<?php

$name = $_POST('name');
$company = $_POST('company');
$email = $_POST('email');
$message = $_POST('message');

$to ="arp2222@yahoo.com";
$subject="New Message from Kincentive";

mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: ".$name);
echo "Your Message has been sent";

?>
```

I want to know how I can make this php work with my html file.  I put the php file in the root folder with the index.html file and I believe I need to set up a form tag.  I believe I need to use the action or method attribute? to setup as

for example.

I am using MAMP PRO as a local host since my site is not live yet and I want to test the contact form and recieve the test to my email.

Any help please i am new to php

Answer (score 1):

in sendEmail.html you should write  code as given

```
<form name="frmEmail" id="frmEmail" action="sendEmail.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
  <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

this form redirect to sendEmail.php

```
<?php
  $name=$_POST['fName'];
  $company=$_POST['company'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  $to =$_POST['email'];
  $subject="New Message from Kincentive";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: ".$name);
  echo "Your Message has been sent";
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Now how do I make the php file talk with the index.html file?  is it a simple: <form action="sendEmail.php" method="POST">...?

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an array, so you should reference it like this, using [ brackets instead of curly ones.

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
```

In your HTML, wrap your inputs in a form like this, pointing to your Php file:

```
<form action="form_process.php" method="POST">

<-- input elements here !-->

</form>
```

Comment: Ok, so in the input elements section I should just put the $_POST array. ex) $_POST[ ];  ? like this? or as seen above as you shown?

Comment: As seen above, the variables you submit via POST are parsed into the $_POST superglobal array, so you can reference them like this: $_POST['name'] etc...